Help with a related rates and optimization problem

Hello this is a problem I am trying to work on that I'm stuck on. I got the general outline setup trying to use the pythagoras theorem but I'm aware that I want to find the x,y values to minimize the time. I also know that I need one more equation probably in order to sub in for the optimization thing and I just don't know what to use. If someone could solve this for me I would appreciate it so I can see where my approach is failing and then I'll ask more questions if I'm still stuck.

Please show more details about the work you have so far and describe where you are stuck.

To be honest I have only really gotten to the Pythagoras theorem r^2=x^2+y+2, and x=200ft dx/dt = 6ft/sec, y=60ft dy/dt=4ft/sec. I dont really know what other equation to use, because I know I'll need another one to make a substitution. And when I take the derivative of the equation to find an extreme I dont know which variable I will be solving for etc.

Try to derive a general equation of time needed to reach the stick first, see where it gets you

The dog's viable strategies is to run along the bank of the river for some distance $d$, and then swim directly to the stick.

When $d=0$, this corresponds to swimming $\sqrt{200^2 + 60^2}$ feet directly to the stick from where it starts.
When $d=200$, this corresponds to running $200$ feet to the closest point of the bank to the stick, and then swimming $60$ feet to the stick.

These are the two extreme choices for $d$. The goal is to find the choice of $d$ in $[0, 200]$ that minimizes the time.

The dog requires $d/6$ seconds to run along the bank for $d$ feet.
From there the distance to the stick is $\sqrt{(200-d)^2 + 60^2}$ feet, so it requires $\sqrt{(200-d)^2 + 60^2}/4$ seconds to swim that distance.

Thus the total time is
$$\frac{d}{6} + \frac{\sqrt{(200 - d^2)+60^2}}{4}.$$
Mininizing this with respect to $d$ is now a standard calculus problem.
